# Azure AD OAuth 2 validate token .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory, token

I am developing now a Microservices .NET Core project. We have an Azure AD and we want to validate the requests that come to all web Apis microservice.

There are many apps who will call our Web API projects. Each one of these app has his own application (ClientId and client secret). They generate the token using their data and then send it in the header with every request. (No problem till now)

On my side, I have to validate the token with every request, but the validation should work for all the tokes that come from different applications.

So, I am trying to set the JWTBarear to accept any token, but I am a bit lost with the configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
   {
      o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   })
   .AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
   {
      jwt.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[myTenant]";
   });

services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
   {
      auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build());
   });
```

and in the Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();   
app.UseMvc();
```

But, I am getting always and 401. I generated the token using postman and it is valid.

I am not very good with the configurations. Am I missing something?
All the examples that I saw on the internet are using ClientId which I have many, not just one.

P.S. I don't have to sign in or something, I have to only validate the token.

Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to specify all of their ids in ValidAudiences. But why does that API allow tokens meant for other APIs?

Comment: @juunas yes exactly, I just found out that. I was searching since yesterday, and I found the Audience in .NET Core. It works now, please see my answer down there. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score -1):

Ooh, I found the answer. I was missing the Audience, which was different in .NET Core:

```
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
       {
           jwtOptions.Audience = "https://management.core.windows.net";
           jwtOptions.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[myTenant]";
       });
```

Comment: Validating tokens that were not intended for _your_ service is very bad practice. You MUST NOT be reading any token that is not intended specifically for your service. In your example above, you're accepting an audience value for the Azure Management API, which is not a service you control. Microsoft could decide to change the token format for its own services at any point in time (e.g. add encryption), and that should not cause any breakage in your solution.

Comment: From [4.1.3 of RFC 7519 JSON Web Token](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.3): "If the principal processing the claim does not identify itself with a value in the "aud" claim when this claim is present, then the JWT MUST be rejected."

Comment: Ooh, this is critical. But then, what do you suggest. Because I have multiple applications, all belong to the same Azure AD. @PhilippeSignoret